# Cannot fully delete an object in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you completely delete an object via the Amazon S3 Console? "Completely delete" meaning the object is entirely gone and isn't visible when enabling "Show versions." I cannot delete the "Show versions" objects themselves as the button is greyed out when they're selected. I've also tried deleting them via CLI but have had no luck.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to delete via awscli? What error message do you see?

Comment: Anon coward below has explained about versioning in S3 buckets. To completely delete an object, you have to toggle versioned views using "show versions" then you can delete it by entering "permanently delete" as confirmation keyword. More on to that here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/DeletingObjectVersions.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have versioning enabled, deleting an object just adds another version of the object, the so called "delete marker".  If you want to remove all versions, including the delete marker, you'll need to enumerate and delete all versions of the object.  For instance, with the Python SDK, you can enumerate and delete them with one line after some setup:

```python
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket("-example-bucket-")  # ARN without the 'arn:aws:s3:::' prefix
key = "example_object.txt"
object = bucket.object_versions.filter(Prefix=key)
versions = len(list(object.all()))
object.delete()
print(f"Deleted {versions} versions for '{key}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your IAM User accessing the bucket does not have s3:DeleteObjectVersion permission. Once you add this permission to your policy, you should be able to delete the versions as well.

Comment: I tried adding DeleteObjectVersion as a policy just now (I attached it to my IAM user) but unfortunately it didn't fix the issue. I'm logged in as the root user if that helps at all.

Comment: @Alexcamostyle Longer term, you would ideally not be using the [root user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html) but that at least confirms that you do have permission (root user has all permission).